# create product rule using bigcommerce API

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to create a product rule using bigcommerce api but i get the error :

"array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1352 (2) { ["status"]=> int(400) ["message"]=> string(55) "The field 'adjustor' is not supported by this resource." } } "

this is my code :

```
        $adjustor = new stdClass() ;  
    $adjustor->adjustor="absolute";
    $adjustor->adjustor_value=14.25;
    $rule = array(
        "sort_order" => 0,
        "is_enabled" => true,
        "is_stop" => false,
        "price_adjuster" => $adjustor,
        "weight_adjuster" => null,
        "is_purchasing_disabled" => false,
        "purchasing_disabled_message" => "",
        "is_purchasing_hidden" => false,
        'conditions' => array($x, $y)
    );
    $result = Bigcommerce::createProductRule($productId, $rule);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($result);
    echo '</pre>';
    if (!$result) {
        $error = Bigcommerce::getLastError();
        var_dump($error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This just looks like a typo. You spelled `adjustor` instead of `adjuster`.

It should be:

```
$adjustor->adjuster="absolute";
$adjustor->adjuster_value=14.25;
```